# iPhone SDK 3.0 Testing

Tags: iphone

We are planning to build an IPhone application which will use some of the Features of the new 3.0 SDK especially the Peer to Peer Connectivity, Our biggest concern at the moment is how can we test the application and the Peer to Peer Connectivity, Do we have to wait for the Launch of the IPhone 3.0 or we can use the IPhone available now to test these things, I want an advice on that as we have to bought the IPhone's for this application and if the SDK 3 features are not testable on the current IPhones then we should delay the buying process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are part of the iphone developer network (http://developer.apple.com/) you can download and test the beta SDK and OS right now. You can install the OS on your iPhone(s) and should be able to test immediately.

Comment: It used to not be this way though.  Only the early beta testers for 2.0 got to get the Betas of the OS before they were released.  Those people numbered about 4000.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that members of the developer program get early access to the 3.0 version of the OS to allow them to start testing now.